# Best way to display number of overspent projects

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I have the first view displayed as:

```
CREATE VIEW Projects AS
    SELECT DepartmentName, 
        COUNT(*)NumberOfProjects,
        OfficeNumber,
        Phone
    FROM   DEPARTMENT AS D JOIN PROJECT AS P
            ON D.DepartmentName = P.Department

    GROUP BY Department;
```

However, I want to display a "NumberOfOverBudgetProjects" for each department in this view. 
I created a view which lists which projects are going over their hourly budget:

```
CREATE VIEW Budgets AS
    SELECT Department, 
        MaxHours AS ProjectMaxHours, SUM(HoursWorked) AS TotalHoursWorked,
        SUM(HoursWorked) - MaxHours AS Balance
    FROM   PROJECT AS P JOIN ASSIGNMENT AS A
        ON P.ProjectID = A.ProjectID
    GROUP BY P.ProjectID;
```

Marketing department should list 2 projects being over budget and Accounting and Finance should both list 0.

Any ideas how I can incorporate a column of "OverBudgetProjects" in the original view? Or by creating a new view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
CREATE VIEW OverBudgetProjects AS
  SELECT p.department, p.projectid
    FROM project p LEFT JOIN assignment a
      ON p.projectid = a.projectid
   GROUP BY p.department, p.projectid
  HAVING MAX(p.maxhours) < SUM(a.hoursworked);

CREATE VIEW Projects AS
  SELECT DepartmentName, 
         COUNT(DISTINCT p.projectid) NumberOfProjects,
         COUNT(DISTINCT o.Projectid) NumberOfOverBudgetProjects,
         OfficeNumber,
         Phone
    FROM department d JOIN project p
      ON d.DepartmentName = p.Department LEFT JOIN OverBudgetProjects o
      ON d.DepartmentName = o.Department
   GROUP BY p.Department;
```

Sample output from issuing

```
SELECT * FROM Projects
```

is

```
| DEPARTMENTNAME | NUMBEROFPROJECTS | NUMBEROFOVERBUDGETPROJECTS | OFFICENUMBER |        PHONE |
|----------------|------------------|----------------------------|--------------|--------------|
|     Accounting |                1 |                          0 |   BLDG01-100 | 360-285-8300 |
|        Finance |                2 |                          0 |   BLDG01-140 | 360-285-8400 |
|      Marketing |                2 |                          2 |   BLDG02-200 | 360-287-8700 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb4770/1)** demo